# Getting fragment offset from struct iphdr

Tags: c, fragment, libpcap, bitwise-and

I want to get `fragment offset` in struct

[struct iphdr](https://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/Linux/Kod/include/linux/ip.h.html)

```
struct iphdr {
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    ihl:4,
        version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    version:4,
        ihl:4;
#else
#error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
    __u8    tos;
    __u16   tot_len;
    __u16   id;
    __u16   frag_off;
    __u8    ttl;
    __u8    protocol;
    __u16   check;
    __u32   saddr;
    __u32   daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
};
```

Accoring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747036/13767076) I build that code :

```
struct iphdr* iph;
printf ("offset = %d \n " ,iph->frag_off &IP_OFFSET); # print 370
printf ("more fragment= %d \n " ,iph->frag_off &IP_MF ); # print 8192
printf ("do not fragment = %d \n " ,iph->frag_off &IP_DF ); # print 0
```

I have catch this packet with libpcap and watch it with `wireshark`
`iph->frag_off` equal to `0x2172` .

offset should be equal to 2960 (like wireshark) but in my calc it's equal to 370

And more fragment need to be 1 (like wireshark)  but in my calc it's equal to 8192
Why is that?

Comment: endianess do **not** define bit order only **`byte`** order. Your ifdefs are wrong\

Comment: @P__J__ that not my ifdef , that copy from https://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/Linux/Kod/include/linux/ip.h.html

Comment: `iph->frag_off equal to 0x2172` Is this real code? Could you post the actual output as-is from the `printf`? Why is `iph->frag_off` equal to `0x2172`? Was it initialized that way? Your code is invalid - `iph` pointer is uninitialized, `iph->` is undefined behavior. `And more fragment need to be 1 but in my calc it's equal to 8192` How are you checking that? Please show and explain "your calc".

Comment: @KamilCuk I have edit the post

Comment: Some questions: 1) what is the value that `pcap_datalink()` returns for the `pcap_t *` you got from libpcap? 2) How did you calculate the value of `iph`?